# Unit Testing with Fat-Free-Framework

Tags: phpunit, fat-free-framework

Is there a way to use PHPUnit where I have a test folder with indexTest.php inside that tests routes in my index.php file?

The fat-free guide gives snippets of code for mocking route requests and POSTS.  I have only managed to get such a test to work if I generate the route directly in my test file with whatever functionality in it.

What I would like is to mock a route with tokens, allow it to run from a route in index.php and through the controller and test f3 variables that should be set by running the route.

```
<?php

class indexTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        $f3 = Base::instance();
// Don't write to STDOUT
        $f3->set('QUIET', true);
        $f3->route('GET /path', function(){ echo 'TEXT'; });

        $this->assertNull($f3->mock('GET /path'));
        $this->assertSame('TEXT', $f3->get('RESPONSE'));

        $f3->route('GET /verify/@answer/@value',
            function($f3, $params){
                $errors = array();

                $answer = $params['answer'];
                $value = $params['value'];

                $prefix = substr($answer, 0, 3);  //pre, ans, pos
                $id = (int)substr($answer, 3);      //question id number (1, 2, 3, 4)
//$value is the input value from user

                $result = check_id($prefix, $id, $value);

                if($result !== true){
                    $errors[] = $result;
                }
                $f3->set('errors', $errors);
                return $errors;
            });

        function check_id($prefix, $id, $value)
        {
            if($prefix == 'pre' || $prefix == 'pos'){

                if($value <= 0 || $value > 180 || $value === NULL){
                    echo 'The input value of ' . $prefix . $id . ' question was out of bounds';
                    return 'The input value of ' . $prefix . $id . ' question was out of bounds';
                }else{
                    return true;
                }

            }else if($prefix == 'ans'){

                if($value < 0 || $value > 10 || $value === NULL){
                    echo 'The value of quiz ans' + $id + ' was out of bounds';
                    return 'The value of quiz ans' + $id + ' was out of bounds';
                }else{
                    return true;
                }

            }else {
                return 'The prefix does not match';
            }
        }

        $this->assertNotNull($f3->mock('GET /verify/ans1/8'));
        $this->assertEmpty($f3->get('RESPONSE')[0]);

        $this->assertNotNull($f3->mock('GET /verify/dsk4/6'));
        $this->assertSame('6', $f3->get('PARAMS.value'));
        $this->assertSame('dsk4', $f3->get('PARAMS.answer'));
        $this->assertEmpty($f3->get('RESPONSE')[0]);

        $this->assertNotNull($f3->mock('GET /verify/pre4/250'));
        $this->assertSame('The input value of pre4 question was out of bounds', $f3->get('errors')[0]);
        $this->assertNotSame('pre4', $f3->get('PARAMS.answer'));

        $f3->set('QUIET',FALSE); // allow test results to be shown later

        $f3->clear('ERROR');  // clear any errors
    }
}
```

I'd prefer not to declare the entire route like this, maybe I am entirely wrong and this is not possible?  The above code works running vendor/bin/phpunit. Relative examples and tutorials are difficult to find on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer

- Separate your controller code from bootstrapping and routing code
- Reuse the routing configuration in your environments, e.g. website, CLI and testing environment
- Use `Base->mock()` in your tests to mock the previously defined routes
- Don't execute `Base->run()` in the testing environment

---

## Long answer

I'm planning for a long time to write an article about testing F3 routes but due the lack of time I will just give some points here instead:

1. Create a reusable file which defines the routes (e.g. a `routes.php` file or a `INI` file with route defintions)
2. Load the routes before running test code. This could be easily done with a custom bootstrap file for PHPUnit (`--bootstrap <FILE>` or use the according directive in PHPUnit's configuration).
3. Write the PHPUnit tests

## Example

The following example is an adaption of my [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Rayne/5afcf404d334465850db):

**bootstrap-website.php**

```
<?php

$f3 = Base::instance();

require 'bootstrap-shared.php';

// [Custom rules only for the website here]

require 'routes.php';

$f3->run();
```

**bootstrap-test.php**

```
<?php

$f3 = Base::instance();

require 'bootstrap-shared.php';

// [Custom rules only for testing environment here]

$f3->set('QUIET', true);
$f3->set('APP.TEST', true);

require 'routes.php';
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * @var $f3 Base
 */

$f3->route('GET /path', function(){ echo 'TEXT'; });
```

**ExampleTest.php**

```
class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function test() {
        // Could also be provided by a custom base TestCase.
        $f3 = Base::instance();

        $this->assertNull($f3->mock('GET /path'));
        $this->assertSame('TEXT', $f3->get('RESPONSE'));
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- `bootstrap-test.php` is the custom bootstrapping file for PHPUnit
- `bootstrap-website.php` is the bootstrapping file for the website
- `bootstrap-shared.php` contains information shared by all environments. The file could include routing information. I separated the routing information in the example: `routes.php`
- `ExampleTest.php` is a regular PHPUnit test
- The `$f3->set('QUIET', true);` snippet should be added to the custom bootstrap file. It's also a good idea to introduce a variable showing that the application is running in a test mode, for instance `$f3->set('APP.TEST', true)`
- F3 doesn't clean up your variables between tests/mocks. You could store the original state before running tests and then restore the state in PHPUnit's `setUp()` method
- Instead of rendering pages it *could* also be sufficient to collect only the data which should be available for rendering. In this case use the introduced `APP.TEST` variable in your view to skip rendering

**Notes for later answer updates**

- `ini_set('error_log','./phpunit/error.log')`
- `$f3->set('ONERROR',function(){});`